# Conditional Formatting Values in Table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set some conditional formatting on values within a table. For example I have 2 columns, 1 Row, so 2 values (1 in each td). I am trying to set the font colour of any values in the row that contain the text "Red" in the table to red.

I don't seem to be getting errors.

RESOLVED:
Final Code:

```
<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
  <? var data = getData(); ?>
<TABLE id="X">

<tbody>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
<tr>
  <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
  <? } ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>

 <style>

 table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family:arial
        }

 tr {
 border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 width: 110%;
    }    

  </style>

</tbody>
</TABLE>
<?!= include('script_rag'); ?>
```

script_rag:

```
<script>
        var table = document.getElementById("X");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {    
                if (col.innerText == "RED") { 
                    col.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
             }
            else
              if (col.innerText == "GREEN") { 
                    col.style.backgroundColor = "#8CC10C";
                    }

            else
              if (col.innerText == "AMBER") { 
                    col.style.backgroundColor = "#FFBF00";
                  }
            }
         }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please show the structure of your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to accomplish by passing each piece of data into a function like that, but if the case is that you have a table, and each cell inside the table might contain the word "red", then I would to it like this.

```
var cells = document.getElementById("#id_of_your_table").getElementsByTagName("td"); //This is an array of the cells (td's)

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].indexOf('Red')) {
        cells[i].css('background-color', 'red')
    }
```

### }

try this script after the table creation

```
<script>
            var table = document.getElementById("table1");
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {    
                    if (col.innerText == "Red") { // You might want to look at other solutions in case the TD should contain more than just "Red"
                        col.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: My fault for not drawing the full picture. I have a spreadsheet from which i am extracting some information on to a google site. (I am using `function getData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("KEY").getSheets()[3]; //Change Sheet ID and Sheet Number if required
  return sheet.getRange(1,2,1,2).getValues(); // The Range ---> (StartingRow, StartingCol, LengthRow, LengthCol)
}`

Comment: Then i am using the script above to create the table combined with `<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<TABLE>

 <tbody>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>

<style>

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family:arial
}

tr {
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
width: 110%;
}    

</style>

</tbody>
</TABLE>`

I am trying to get any text=Red to be displayed in red.

Comment: So if you create the table, then you can create it with an ID. <TABLE id="tableSpreadSheat"> and then use the code I posted in my answer. It is important that you use my code after the table has been created, and that you use the same ID in the table and in my code. Inside the if(), you get a variable called "cells[i]" as shown. This is all the "elements in the loop" with Red in them, so apply what styles you want there

Comment: is this what you mean: `<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<TABLE id="table1">

 <tbody>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>



</tbody>
</TABLE>

<script>
var cells = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName("td"); //This is an array of the cells (td's)

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].indexOf('Red')) {
        cells[i].css('background-color', 'red')
    }
}
</script>`